# find all edges in a weighed tree that are heaviest edges in some cycle

Tags: algorithms, graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and a weight function $w:E\to\{1,2,3,\dots,10\}$:

Let $U\subseteq E$ the set of **all** edges $e\in E$ that has a cycle in $G$ such that the cycle contains $e$ and all the edges in the cycle are not of heavier weight than $e$.

Find an algorithm that computes $U$.

I have found an algorithm to do it using a modified version of Kruskal algorithm and the union find data structure in $\mathcal{O}(|V|+|E|\alpha(|V|,|E|)$.

My TA said that it can be computed using a linear time algorithm, can you help? I thought of something about modifying the Prim algorithm and then using $10$ Queues for each weight.

Comment: 1. You seem to have already figured out that this problem is an obfuscated form of a slight restriction of a very well-known graph theory problem; why not spell this out, to save answerers some time?  2. Hint: First consider a restriction in which every edge has weight 1.  What algorithm solves this problem?

Comment: Hint: there are only 10 possible values for the weight.  You can do all sorts of things, like sorting by weight, in $O(1)$ time per edge (e.g., counting sort).

Comment: @j_random_hacker If all edges are of weight $1$ we just need to run DFS and find all back edges in linear time. But how can we expand this?

Comment: @D.W. I used sorting in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ for the modified Kruskal algorithm but still you have to use the union find which makes the algorithm above linear time.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thank you I figured it out!

Comment: Now suppose the graph has edge weights in $\{1, \dots, 10\}$.  Think about the subgraph consisting of all edges of weight 1.  What could you safely do as a first step?

Comment: I figured it out first u use only edges of weight 1 and find back edges than with weights 1,2 and so on till 1,2,...,10

Comment: Great!  I was writing my latest hint before seeing this; I'll delete it in a moment (unless you would rather leave it there for posterity).

Comment: Leave it for more to come

Comment: OK.  But the comment you made (and since deleted) suggests that you might not quite have it yet; I see no way to know whether you should DFS through a weight-2 edge or not if there are still weight-1 edges present in the graph.  Maybe you could do *something* to get rid of those weight-1 edges after finding them...?

Comment: What I mean is that u start from the graph of all edges of weight 1 and find the back edges then put them in $U$. Then you add the weight 2 edges and find back edges, the edges you found now are added to $U$ only if their weight is 2 and so on. @j_random_hacker